# How to get value from a table base on "Preference"

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am attempting to get a value from a table based on "Preference".

I have a table "t1" including two columns "id" and "alphabet"

Sample data

```
1 A
1 B
2 A
3 A
3 B
```

It means every id has the default value "A" and some have "B").

Now I would like to get the values of "id" based on preference of "B". Thus,  if an ID has both A and B, I want the B row. If no B row is found, then the default A should be returned.

Comment: yes there is only one value in a single column.... either A or B

Comment: So you want all rows, right? Do you just want to sort on alphabet? Use ORDER BY alphabet if that's the case. If I'm misunderstanding, I don't get what you mean by "get all the id whose alphabet is B and those who has not B then I can get value of A". Please explain further

Comment: Can you post your table structure, sample data and the desired result?

Comment: actually i want all id means 1,2,3 but in a single time having preference of alphabets B(not A's id)  and those hasn't B then its ok i have to take their id from A.....Got it??

Comment: @AshishGinotra actually no, your question is not very clear.  Please edit your post with additional details like table structure, sample data and desired result.

Comment: Yelling at other users is most often counter productive. Please take a moment and re-read the [faq], maybe specifically [faq#etiquette] this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be slightly off as mysql dialect always throws me. Since B falls after A in an alphabetical sort, if you group on the ID and then select the maximum, it will give you all the B rows where they exist, otherwise you will get the A row.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(alphabet) AS preference
FROM
    t1
GROUP BY
    ID
```

Now, if your data is more complex than what you've indicated, you will need to examine whether the MAX logic still applies.

Comment: hiiii billinkc.... firstly thanks to you for understanding my question & editing it.. 2ndly thanks to you for solving it..... really its works whats i want..... thanks alot billinkc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find questions or answers helpful on the site, click the Up arrow next to them. If this has answered, your question, click the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: hey billinkc ... there is also a one prob. IF there are one more column then its not getting value acc. to "alphabet". Plz tell me how could it be possible