# How can i get all the unique id having more than one id with different address

Tags: mysql, select

```
id id2  id3 address 
1   1   0   A   
2   1   0   B
3   2   0   A
4   3   0   A
5   3   0   B
6   4   0   A
```

Hello every one ... plz solve my query... i have this table in this format. Now i want to get value from this table accordingly uniquely "id2" . It means I want all the values having address "B" along with "A"(but "A" should not have same "id2" as  to B). Thus I'll get all the unique values of "id2"....plz guys...do something

currently I'm using the query for getting "B"

```
 SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE address=(SELECT MAX(address) FROM t1)
```

now also i want all the "A" but it should not have same "id2" with "B"

I want its ans

```
id id2  id3 address 

2   1   0   B
3   2   0   A

5   3   0   B
6   4   0   A
```

any idea???

Comment: what is your expected output based on your sample records.

Comment: id id2  id3 address 
2   1   0   B
3   2   0   A
5   3   0   B
6   4   0   A

Comment: [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511536/how-to-get-value-from-a-table-base-on-prefrence)

Comment: @billinkc: YES billinkc...yesterday it was working but it was not taken the all values of a row... so, i again put this question..... Well!!! now i solve it fynally n got it its answer....thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id2, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY id2
        ) b ON  a.id2 = b.id2 aND
                a.ID = b.max_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f72/21)